# SSIS Odata source

Tags: sharepoint, ssis, odata

Hi I am trying to use the Odata connection manager to SharePoint

I keep getting the following

> Need to to change DTDprocessing property on XMLreader settings to parse...

Where can this be done please ?

Just want to link to table in share point

Please help

Comment: Screenshots would be nice to begin with to be able to help.

Comment: Would like to but to be honest it's a work . I just can't find the dtd processing setting or property to change..do you know where it is please?